# Can I add cement glue and sand into my concrete mix to repair my cenent garden statue?

Tags: repair, concrete, diy-vs-pro

I have a leopard concrete garden statue that was given to me by my neighbor that has a broken foot and log. I want to repair it and paint it. It also has been weather eroded so I need to recover it as well. I was wondering if I could mix up concrete, add sand and concrete glue in the mix? I know I will have to put concrete glue to the top of the statue to help bond the mix to it. I hope someone can answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a good idea, but you dont need to use concrete like the quikrete bags with big rock, make your own using portland and sand, and adding the glue will help!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

When repairing concrete you have to keep a few things:

1. The consistency, or grit of the existing concrete that you are repairing.This would also include any aggregate in the original concrete (you should be able to see that where it's broken)
2. Any additional treatments or patina you want to preserve or make consistent with the repair.
3. The weight being loaded on the repaired portion, if it is substantial you make have to reinforce the broken bit with rebar, or a like material.
4. The final placement of the piece (outdoors, indoors, heat, etc.) as this will limit you choices in terms of finishing product.

In your case, I believe that you are on the right track and like another answer you shouldn't use something like Quickcrete, but make your own with Portland, Sand and Water. Additional, you may want to consider a concrete adhesive depending on the size of the break and use your homemade concrete to blend the edges prior to refinishing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mixing your own i think it would be easier to use a premixed product such as

[QUIKRETE 10-lbs Vinyl Concrete Patch](https://quikrete.com/productlines/vinylconcretepatcher.asp)

or

[Sakrete Fast Setting 10-lbs Cement Concrete Patch](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sakrete-Fast-Setting-10-lbs-Cement-Concrete-Patch/3093931)

I have used the first one and it worked well. It has some adhesive in it and there is no aggregate ( rocks ) in it so you can smooth it and shape it. It is fast setting but you have time to work with it.
if the repair you are doing is thick you would build it up in layers or go with another kind of premixed patch that is for thicker applications.

I would do a test run with it so you get a feel for the working time and how to shape it.